# $o(x)$ and $O(x^2)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, asymptotics

How to prove, that $O(x^2) \subset o(x) $ when $x \to 0$? How should i use the definitions of  Big O : $ \exists C>0, \exists \delta : |x|<\delta, |f(x)| \leq C|x^2| $ and little o: $\forall \epsilon>0 \> \exists \delta>0  : 0<|x|<\delta, |f(x)| \leq \epsilon|x| $ if the first definition mentions two constants and the second has $\forall \epsilon>0$?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Do you know the general strategy for showing that $A \subset B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x) = O(x^2)$,
then there are $c>0$
and $d > 0$
such that
$f(x) < cx^2$
for $|x| < d$.

Therefore,
for $|x| < d$,
$\frac{f(x)}{x} < c|x|$.

You want to show that,
for any $\delta > 0$,
there is an $\epsilon > 0$
such that
$|\frac{f(x)}{x}|
< \delta 
$
for
$|x| < \epsilon
$.

In 
$\frac{f(x)}{x} < c|x|$,
to make
$\frac{f(x)}{x} < \epsilon$,
choose
$c|x| < \epsilon$,
or
$|x| < \epsilon/c$.

Therefore,
if
$|x| < \min(d, \epsilon/c)$.
$\frac{f(x)}{x} < \epsilon$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "for any ϵ>0, there is an δ>0 such that |f(x)x|<ϵ for |x|<δ"?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

First, write out what it means for $f(x)=O(x^2)$; that is, there is a $C$ so that 
$|f(x)|\le Cx^2$ for $x$ near $0$.

Next, $f(x)=o(x)$ means that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=0$.

Comment: In my comment to the post below i did some limit technics, but i don't fully understand the relation between a fixed neighbourhood where $|f(x)|\le Cx^2$ and the limit, that goes to zero. Can i use this inequality in the limit if it is right only for the fixed neighbourhood?

Comment: You need to understand what the definitions given mean. I have merely transcribed them to a form that is more meaningful, at least to me. $$\exists C>0, \exists \delta : |x|<\delta, |f(x)| \leq C|x^2|$$ simply says that there is a $C$ so that $|f(x)|\le Cx^2$ for $x$ is near $0$ (within a distance of $\delta$). $$\forall \epsilon>0 \> \exists \delta>0  : 0<|x|<\delta, |f(x)| \leq \epsilon|x|$$ is just another way of saying that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{|f(x)|}{|x|}=0$. Note that this second statement is only interesting for small $\epsilon$.

Comment: Note that, once we have the last condition for some $\epsilon$, it is vacuously true for all greater $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following fact:
if $g(x)\neq 0$ on an interval $I$ centered around $0$, and $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \xrightarrow[x\to 0]{} C > 0$, then  $f(x) = O(g(x))$. Similarly, if $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \xrightarrow[x\to 0]{} 0$, then  $f(x) = o(g(x))$

Comment: Seems something like $\forall f(x) \in O(x^2) : \lim_{x\to 0} | \frac{f(x)}{x} | = \lim_{x\to 0} | \frac{f(x)}{x^2} ||x| = \lim_{x\to 0} C|x| = 0$, so $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} = 0$. Is it right?

Comment: Yes -- the limit has to be zero, has $f(x)$ behaves "at most like $x^2$ (i.e., goes to 0 much faster than $x$).